# Design conflict with <a> and <article>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with the [jquery.accordion.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/accordion/Responsive-Multi-Level-Accordion-Menu-Plugin.html) library, and everything is fine, but I have some kind of conflict with the design, when I try to wrap an `<article>` with an `<a>` tag the design changes. With Test2 I have the design that I want, but with Test the design changes because I'm using an `<a>` tag around the `<article>` tag. And I want that when the user click on the row(it doesn't need to be just the letters) the action to get executed, that's why I want to use `<article>` embedded in an `<a>` tag, otherwise if I put the `<a>` tag inside `<article>` the action will be executed only when the user clicks on the words, not the entire row, do you know why this is happening? Or if you have other suggestion to do this would be welcome :)

```
<section id="demo" data-accordion-group>
<data-accordion>
 <article data-control class="rounded test hand">Test</article>
        <div data-content>
            <a asp-action="Download" asp-controller="Apps" asp-route-folder="FolderName" asp-route-file="NameWithExtension"> <article class="articleItem">FileName</article></a>
            <a asp-action="Download" asp-controller="Apps" asp-route-folder="FolderName" asp-route-file="NameWithExtension"> <article class="articleItem">FileName</article></a>
            <a asp-action="Download" asp-controller="Apps" asp-route-folder="FolderName" asp-route-file="NameWithExtension"> <article class="articleItem">FileName</article></a>

            <article data-control class="rounded test hand"> Test2</article>
<div data-content>    

  <article class="articleItem hand" data-folder="FolderName" data-file="FileName"><a asp-action="Download" asp-controller="Apps" asp-route-folder="FolderName" asp-route-file="NameWithExtension">FileName</a></article>
        <article class="articleItem hand" data-folder="FolderName" data-file="FileName"><a asp-action="Download" asp-controller="Apps" asp-route-folder="FolderName" asp-route-file="NameWithExtension">FileName</a></article>
        <article class="articleItem hand" data-folder="FolderName" data-file="FileName"><a asp-action="Download" asp-controller="Apps" asp-route-folder="FolderName" asp-route-file="NameWithExtension">FileName</a></article>
        <article class="articleItem hand" data-folder="FolderName" data-file="FileName"><a asp-action="Download" asp-controller="Apps" asp-route-folder="FolderName" asp-route-file="NameWithExtension">FileName</a></article>[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

[image: Design problem:]

[image]

Just in case I'm putting my CSS code if you need to see it:

```
<style type="text/css">  

    .rounded {
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#87CEEB;
    border-color:#bce8f1;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
    }

    .articleItem {
    background-color:#e6f3f7;
    max-width:700px;
    border-radius:5px;
    }

    .test {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;       
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #446e98;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .content {
    position:relative;
    }

    .imgRight {       
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    max-height:90px;
    max-width:90px;
    }
    .hand:hover {
  cursor: pointer; }

.articleItem:hover {
    background-color: #d6edf3 !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C# or asp.net-mvc?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli thanks, it's fixed now :)

Comment: Wow... "how not to write HTML" 101. However, if you set the `<a>` inside the `<article>` (in the test2-example) to `display: block;` it will cover the whole row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `<a>` is an inline element by default, so that's why you get those anomalies.

Solution: turn them into blocks by adding

```
div[data-content] a {display:block}
```

to the CSS.

By the way, you should should really run your page through a validator.

Comment: It worked, I don't know why someone downvoted your answer because it works,

Comment: @AlexGH Probably because junkfoodjunkie's comment was already up when I hit post, and it may have looked like I copied their remark into an answer for easy points.